# The covariance of the parameters cannot be estimated during curve fitting

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm trying to solve two unknown parameters based on my function expression using the *scipy.optimize.curve_fit function*.  The equation I used is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQDdQ.png)

My code is as follows:

```
p_freqs =np.array(0.,8.19672131,16.39344262,24.59016393,32.78688525,
                  40.98360656,49.18032787,57.37704918,65.57377049,73.7704918,
                  81.96721311,90.16393443,98.36065574,106.55737705,114.75409836,
                  122.95081967,131.14754098,139.3442623, 147.54098361,155.73770492,
                  163.93442623,172.13114754,180.32786885,188.52459016,196.72131148,
                  204.91803279,213.1147541, 221.31147541,229.50819672,237.70491803,
                  245.90163934)
p_fft_amp1 = np.array(3.34278536e-08,5.73549829e-08,1.94897033e-08,1.59088184e-08,
                      9.23948302e-09,3.71198908e-09,1.85535722e-09,1.86064653e-09,
                      1.52149363e-09,1.33626573e-09,1.19468040e-09,1.08304535e-09,
                      9.96594475e-10,9.25671797e-10,8.66775330e-10,8.17287132e-10,
                      7.75342888e-10,7.39541296e-10,7.08843676e-10,6.82440637e-10,
                      6.59712650e-10,6.40169517e-10,6.23422124e-10,6.09159901e-10,
                      5.97134297e-10,5.87146816e-10,5.79040074e-10,5.72691200e-10,
                      5.68006964e-10,5.64920239e-10,5.63387557e-10)
def  cal_omiga_tstar(omiga,tstar,f):
    return omiga*np.exp(-np.pi*f*tstar)/(1+(f/18.15)**2)
omiga,tstar = optimize.curve_fit(cal_omiga_tstar,p_freqs,p_fft_amp1)[0]
```

When I run the code I get the following prompt:
`OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't exactly pinpoint the cause of your error message because your code had some errors prior to that. First, the construction of the two arrays has invalid syntax, then your definition of `cal_omiga_tstar` has the wrong argument order. While fixing these problems I did get your error message once, but I haven't been able to reproduce it, weirdly enough. However, I did manage to fit your function. You should supply initial guesses to the parameters, especially since your `y` has so many low values. There's no magic here, just plot your model and data until it's relatively close. Then, let the algorithm take the wheel.

Here's my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

# Changed here, was "np.array(0.,..."
p_freqs =np.array([0.,8.19672131,16.39344262,24.59016393,32.78688525,
                  40.98360656,49.18032787,57.37704918,65.57377049,73.7704918,
                  81.96721311,90.16393443,98.36065574,106.55737705,114.75409836,
                  122.95081967,131.14754098,139.3442623, 147.54098361,155.73770492,
                  163.93442623,172.13114754,180.32786885,188.52459016,196.72131148,
                  204.91803279,213.1147541, 221.31147541,229.50819672,237.70491803,
                  245.90163934])
p_fft_amp1 = np.array([3.34278536e-08,5.73549829e-08,1.94897033e-08,1.59088184e-08,
                      9.23948302e-09,3.71198908e-09,1.85535722e-09,1.86064653e-09,
                      1.52149363e-09,1.33626573e-09,1.19468040e-09,1.08304535e-09,
                      9.96594475e-10,9.25671797e-10,8.66775330e-10,8.17287132e-10,
                      7.75342888e-10,7.39541296e-10,7.08843676e-10,6.82440637e-10,
                      6.59712650e-10,6.40169517e-10,6.23422124e-10,6.09159901e-10,
                      5.97134297e-10,5.87146816e-10,5.79040074e-10,5.72691200e-10,
                      5.68006964e-10,5.64920239e-10,5.63387557e-10])
# Changed sequence from "omiga, tstar, f" to "f, omiga, tstar".
def  cal_omiga_tstar(f, omiga,tstar):
    return omiga*np.exp(-np.pi*f*tstar)/(1+(f/18.15)**2)

# Changed this call to get popt, pcov, and supplied the initial guesses
popt, pcov = curve_fit(cal_omiga_tstar,p_freqs,p_fft_amp1, p0=(1E-5, 1E-2))
```

Here's `popt`: `array([ 4.51365934e-08, -1.48124194e-06])` and `pcov`: `array([[1.35757744e-17, 3.54656128e-12],[3.54656128e-12, 2.90508007e-06]])`. As you can see, the covariance matrix could be estimated in this case.

Here's the model x data curve:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since the parameters in the equation are positive, I have added new control conditions: ` omiga,tstar =ptimize.curve_fit(cal_omiga_tstar,f,of,bounds=((0., 0.), (1E-5,1E-2)))[0]`. However, this effect is a little worse. Is there another algorithm can do that?

Comment: In my case, the second parameter was negative. With your restriction, the algorithm will try to find the best that it can. `curve_fit` has other algorithms that you can use, see its documentation. If I helped you, don't forget to accept my answer